# When downloading a m3u8 video with multi-process, some content are missing. I wonder why it happened and how to solve this problem?

Tags: python-requests, python-multithreading, m3u8

I want to download an m3u8 video using `requests` lib. The url of this file is http://livenging.alicdn.com/mediaplatform/ddc3dfe9-240c-4ed2-b949-90a4707cdf59_merge.m3u8.

First I try to download this video directly, the code is shown below:

```py
r = requests.get(url)
m3u8_list = r.text.split('\n')
m3u8_list = [ts_url for ts_url in m3u8_list if ts_url and ts_url[0] != '#']

for i, ts_url in enumerate(m3u8_list):
    r = requests.get(ts_url)
    with open('ts/' + str(content_id) + f'{i}.ts', 'wb') as f:
        if r.status_code == 200:
            f.write(r.content)
```

The code run successfully, but is a bit slow consider my demand. So I try multiprocess using `threading` lib, and create one thread for one `ts_url`. The process is:

```py
threads = []
    
for i, ts_url in enumerate(m3u8_list):
    ts_file_path = 'ts/' + str(content_id) + f'{i}.ts'
    thread = Downloader(url, ts_url, ts_file_path)
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)
    
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

The `Downloader` class is a subclass of `threading.Thread`:

```py
class Downloader(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, url, ts_url, file_path):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.url = url
        self.ts_url = ts_url
        self.file_path = file_path

    def run(self):
        r = requests.get(self.ts_url, stream=True, timeout=10)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            with open(self.file_path, 'wb') as f:
                for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
                    if chunk:
                        f.write(chunk)
```

This code create an `ts` file for a `ts_url`, too, but many subvideo lose their completeness! I wonder why it happened and how to solve this problem. Anyway I need a method to download video successfully and download as fast as possible.

I have explored the influence of `r.iter_content`, and delete the parameter of `stream=True`. The code is like:

```
class Downloader(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, url, ts_url, file_path):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.url = url
        self.ts_url = ts_url
        self.file_path = file_path

    def run(self):
        r = requests.get(self.ts_url, timeout=10)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            with open(self.file_path, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(r.content)
```

And it produce similar result with the exists of `stream=True`.